# How to unsubscribe and resubscribe after timespan?

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

I need to unsubscribe and then resubscribe or somehow pause and ignore all emitted values of an Observable.

In my component I subscribe to my Observable:

```
    this.controllingSubscription =
  this.route.params
    .switchMap(p => this.controllingService.getSaleComparison(p)
    .subscribe(res => {
      this.controlEnt = res;
      this.isLoading = false;
    });
```

In the service, I check for the existenece of the Object and if not, push a task to a queue where a server picks up the task and gets the information:

```
this.af.list(`wawi/statistics/salesVolComparison/${platformId}/${year}/${month}`)
          .do(res => {
            if(res.length === 0)
              this.af.list('queue/tasks').push({task: 'salesComparison', platform: platformId, year: year, month: month});
          })
```

The problem is, the server then pushes the list to the db and the client gets the list for every entry. So if I have 1000 entries, I get back 1000 responses, every response with one more entry, instead of one response with the whole list.

Does anybody know how to solve that problem? Thanks.

Comment: Does that observable ever complete? If so you could use `.last` to extract only the final value.

Comment: No, I unsubscribe when destroying the view. I use .debounceTime now, but would be interesting if there is another alternative.

Comment: To clarify, you have a server process that watches `queue/tasks` and performs the requested processing and your list then emits the results cumulatively: `[], [1], [1, 2], [1, 2, 3]` And you only want `[1, 2, 3]`, right?

Comment: Yeah, thats my problem